# used heap size of user process from kernel module

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am writing a kernel module which will accept user process id (`PID`) as input and dump all the address space of that user process,like stack,heap segment.

I took `mm->start_brk` as start of heap, `mm->brk` as end of heap,then i am seeing, even though user process is not using 33 pages, heap size shows as 33 pages
 (`mm->brk` - `mm->start_brk`). (This i verified using `/proc/pid/maps`). Stack also behaves in similar way.

So is there any way i can find out the really used heap staring from `mm->start_brk`, So that i can dump only the used heap.

Answer (score 2):

A process can allocate memory with `brk` and with `mmap`. The latter doesn't change the heap, but allocates separately.

`mm->mmap` is a linked list of mappings created by `mmap`.

Comment: Thank  you ugoren,But question is, i am dumping heap memory of a user process using my kernel module.The user process i used for testing is  doing a malloc of few byte only.But from kernel module i can see kernel at first time give around 32 Page(33*4K) of heap memory( cat /proc/pid/maps alsow will explain this ).In that only few bytes are used by my test user process and all other is zero.So i just want to find the exactly used region of heap.Not the mm->brk - mm->start_brk

Comment: The way the process manages the heap isn't known to the kernel. If it asked the kernel for 32 pages, then as far as the kernel is concerned, it has 32 pages. You might check which are mapped to physical memory - pages never touched wouldn't be mapped.

Comment: My test progarm is like below doing malloc of 10 byte, and when i do cat /proc/<pid>/maps of this program i am seeing it heap size as 33 pages.So that means when exec brk will call with default 33 page?            --------------------------------------------include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char *ptr;
        while(1)
        {
                ptr = malloc(10);
                free(ptr);
        }
}                                                                   cat /proc/pid/maps                                             082f4000-08315000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]

Comment: It's up to libC and the kernel to decide how to handle `malloc`. libC probably asks for 32 pages in advance, so next `malloc`s will be cheaper.

Comment: Yes your are absolutely correct ,from man page of mmap,"MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128 kB (32*4KB page )by
default, but is adjustable using mallopt(3)" ,So can we conclude like from kernel side we wont be able know  how much heap really used by the  process ??